# Using redux-logger, can no longer expand object within VS Code Debug Console

Tags: redux, visual-studio-code, angular6, vscode-debugger

I am not sure what relates to what yet or what is truly at fault, but in the process of upgrading from Angular 5.2.6 => 6.0.4, my redux-logger, which still functions outside of debug mode (i.e. reading it from Chrome console), no longer works properly when debugging in Visual Studio Code.  The output is there, but I can no longer expand any of the objects (the arrow goes down, but nothing is rendered).  I can go back to my previous Angular 5 project and it works fine [note: redux and redux-logger versions are the same: 3.7.2 and 3.0.6 respectively]; that being said, a lot of other things were upgraded (but I would expect it not to function at all if it were having issues).  Has anyone else experienced this and/or has a solution as the primary place I use the logger is in debug mode since it won't let me inspect the browser console when in debug mode?

Note: originally posted here: https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger/issues/303